# How to assign GUIText from heirarchy into prefab object?

Tags: c#, unity, gui

I want to assign GUIText from heirarchy into prefab using that C# code:

```
    private Text HighScoreText;

    void Start(){
 HighScoreText = GameObject.Find("HighScore").GetComponent();

    }
```

But that works only if my present prefab object isn't prefab and is in hierarchy. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html will use to search in hierarchy i guess

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to save some scores to be used on the next game runs, right? If so it's not that straight forward. Basically when the game stops everything is lost. To make something be saved and used on the next runs you need serialization. On the other hand there is an easy to use but easy to cheat by players way - [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html), you will need to use [PlayerPrefs.SetFloat](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetFloat.html) and [PlayerPrefs.GetFloat](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetFloat.html) or their Int counterparts [SetInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html) and [GetInt](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.GetInt.html).

Comment: I'm using PlayerPrefs.SetIng and GetInt to save score but I want to show it using GUIText. And that works if my player object is in heirarchy too, but not works when my player object isn't in heirarchy and is prefab, then I can't drag and drop into inspector panel my GUIText element to connect it with my player. So I wanted assign that GUI element into my player by the c# script and GameObject.Find...

Sorry for bad eng

Comment: There is some problem with your overall structure. Player should not have any highscore related code. Separate Highscore and Player completely. You may create an Object called Highscore , it could have 2 ints, currentScore and highScore, make so that when currentScore is bigger than highscore then highScore = currentScore. Then attach GUIText to Highscore object and display highScore. Then you will only need to change currentScore.

Comment: Yeah, I removed all GUI code and elements from player script and I made another scripts for collect points, HS and display GUI and all works perfectly. Thanks again for advice. :)